# BASH - how can i make the log file accessable via TCP port when-ever requires?

Tags: linux, bash, tcp

How can i have a logs on TCP port available, so that it can be remotely tested by someone else ? for example:

```
MAINSERVER> tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/access_log | grep -e fruit_Python -e fruit_BASH -e fruit_C | .... TCP 9999 ... make this available ....??
```

NOW, from my Laptop remotely i want to do this temporary:

```
MYLAPTOP> tail -f http://MAINSERVER:9999 | grep -e grab_BASH
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use netcat (nc) to do this:

Server side (listen for connection):

```
tail -f /foo/bar |nc -l -k -p 9999
```

-l listen

-k listen for another connection after current completed

Client side (connecting):

```
nc MAINSERVER 9999 | grep whatever_you_like
```

You can use bash as well to connect to /dev/tcp/host/port but sometimes it's not suported (compiled in to Bash) for security reasons.

Client:

```
grep whatever_you_like < /dev/tcp/MAINSERVER/9999
```